# Maven checkstyle plugin. CheckstyleException: Property 'accessModifiers' in module ParameterName does not exist

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I'm trying to use the checkstyle plugin with a custom checkstyle file named `checkstyle.xml`. [I have followed the guide](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html). This is my POM:

```
...
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
...
```

and `checksyle.xml` is [the google checkstyle file](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) (I've only renamed the file). The problem is that, when I run `mvn -X site`, I obtain the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: Failed during checkstyle configuration
at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.AbstractCheckstyleReport.executeReport(AbstractCheckstyleReport.java:488)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.CheckstyleReport.executeReport(CheckstyleReport.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:219)
... 26 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Property 'accessModifiers' in module ParameterName does not exist, please check the documentation
at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:168)
at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.exec.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle(DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:218)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.AbstractCheckstyleReport.executeReport(AbstractCheckstyleReport.java:473)
... 29 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Property 'accessModifiers' in module ParameterName does not exist, please check the documentation
at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.tryCopyProperty(AutomaticBean.java:164)
at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:130)
at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.TreeWalker.setupChild(TreeWalker.java:177)
at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AutomaticBean.configure(AutomaticBean.java:137)
at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.Checker.setupChild(Checker.java:163)
... 32 more
```

I checked the checkstyle file and I have the `accessModifiers` properties defined.

```
....
<module name="ParameterName">
    <property name="id" value="ParameterNameNonPublic"/>
    <property name="format" value="^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$"/>
    <property name="accessModifiers" value="protected, package, private"/>
    <message key="name.invalidPattern" value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
</module>
<module name="ParameterName">
    <property name="id" value="ParameterNamePublic"/>
    <property name="format" value="^[a-z][a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
    <property name="accessModifiers" value="public"/>
    <message key="name.invalidPattern" value="Parameter name ''{0}'' must match pattern ''{1}''."/>
</module>
```

So, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `<configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>` is what the guide suggests.

Comment: Looks like accessModifiers was introduced in recent version of checkstyle plugin to replace scope. Does it work if you remove the accessModifiers elements? Also try to use latest plugin in your (by defualt its 6.11.2)configuration as per below,https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html

Comment: @nullpointer The file is just in a different position.

Answer (score 0):

***accessModifiers*** was introduced only in checkstyle release 7.5. Please see the release notes below.
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html

1. You can make module definition compatible with older version by
   removing the accessModifiers and adding scope instead.
2. You can specify the latest version in the checkstyle plugin
   definition as mentioned here (by defualt its 6.11.2)

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading- checkstyle.html

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html

Comment: I've tried with the 7.5 version, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @giuseta how are you changing it to 7.5? Are you declaring pluginmanagment to override the dependency? I am able to get it to work

Comment: Also look at question that I asked ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121531/dependencies-added-in-pluginmanagement-not-considered-during-reporting/42122294#42122294