# Dependencies added in pluginManagement not considered during reporting

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

I am trying to configure the Maven Checkstyle Plugin for reporting and would like to change the dependency of Checkstyle to 7.5 instead of the default 6.11.2.

To achieve this I, have `pluginManagement` declared in parent pom with the dependency.
In the child project, I am just referencing the plugin in the reporting tag.

However I see that default Checkstyle (6.11.2) is being downloaded into the repository. Please see below parent and child pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent_app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>parent_app</name>
  <modules>
    <module>my-app2</module>
  </modules>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
              <version>7.5</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Child pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent_app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app2</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
   <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
</project>
```

Can you please help if this is the right way to override dependency for reporting plugin? If so why is it not working?

**Maven version: 3.2.5**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug here with the Maven Site Plugin (a regression introduced after [MSITE-507](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-507)). The dependencies explicitly added to the managed plugins configured in the build are indeed not taken into account, unless the plugin is also declared itself. That is to say, the following in the parent POM will give you the wanted behaviour (tested with Maven 3.3.9):

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

When that new parent is installed in the local repository, and the build on the child is launched (with `mvn clean site` for example), it is the expected Checkstyle 7.5 that will be used.

Comment: @Santo FYI, I logged the bug in [MSHARED-616](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-616) and the fix will probably make it into the next version of the Site Plugin.